# Image instead of Symbol SplitView.Pane Item Icon

Tags: c#, uisplitviewcontroller, uwp

I want to use a image (PNG) to set it as a icon for a SplitView.Pane item. There is no icons that in Sagoe MDL2 font. I know that it is recomended to use vector font but I realy need to replace that with a png image. Here is how it work now:

XAML
...

```
<SplitView.Pane>
                <!-- A custom ListView to display the items in the pane.  The automation Name is set in the ContainerContentChanging event. -->
                <controls:NavMenuListView x:Name="NavMenuList"
                                          TabIndex="3"
                                          Margin="0,48,0,0"
                                          ContainerContentChanging="NavMenuItemContainerContentChanging"
                                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NavMenuItemContainerStyle}"
                                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavMenuItemTemplate}"
                                          ItemInvoked="NavMenuList_ItemInvoked">
</SplitView.Pane>
```

Adding items to navigation list
Code:

```
private List<NavMenuItem> navlist = new List<NavMenuItem>(
            new[]
            {
        new NavMenuItem()
                {

                    Symbol = Symbol.Shop,
                    Label = "Go to shop",
                    DestinationPage = typeof(Views.Page1)
                }
            });
```

And the `NavMenuItem` class:

```
public class NavMenuItem
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public Symbol Symbol { get; set; }
        public char SymbolAsChar
        {
            get
            {
                return (char)this.Symbol;
            }
        }

        public Type DestinationPage { get; set; }
        public object Arguments { get; set; }

    }
```

And one more question to not open another topic. How to open a left pane on settings button press like in Windows 10 Mail app?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uri instead of the symbol.

```
public Uri IconUri {get; set;}
```

and in `NavMenuItemTemplate` use an `Image` and bind its `Source` property to `IconUri`.

To open the pane, just set IsPaneOpen to true.

```
splitView.IsPaneOpen = true;
```

Comment: Can you please provide some details :( I'm a newbie. Sorry.
`<Style x:Key="NavMenuItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource SplitViewCompactPaneThemeLength}"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source=}"
                </Grid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>`